# Visual Studio: loss of Designer page in Win App Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I've just gone to rename my Form from Form1 to something more appropriate, however on doing so I forgot to add .cs as the file extension. I changed the name of the form back to form1.cs and when I complied my project it ran fine. However, I no longer have the ability to use the Form designer, when I right click the Form1.cs and choose "View Designer", It opens the designer code, where before this it would open the form editing page, where i can move controls around etc etc.

I really cant think of a way to get this back? I really need to get this back.

Below is the csproj code :-

```
<Compile Include="Form1.cs">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Form1.Designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>Form1.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Form1.resx">
      <DependentUpon>Form1.cs</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Properties\Resources.resx">
      <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <Compile Include="Properties\Resources.Designer.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
    </Compile>
    <None Include="app.config">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </None>
    <None Include="packages.config" />
    <None Include="Properties\Settings.settings">
      <Generator>SettingsSingleFileGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Settings.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </None>
    <Compile Include="Properties\Settings.Designer.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Settings.settings</DependentUpon>
      <DesignTimeSharedInput>True</DesignTimeSharedInput>
    </Compile>
```

Comment: Its still the same, I cant edit my controls, its just taking me straight to the designer code? Is there no way to get this back?

Comment: What was "something more appropriate", if you have managed to give it the name of "Form" instead it may have caused a circular reference.

Comment: Given the `csproj` file you just pasted still contains old names (`<Compile Include="Form1.cs">` etc.), why don't you simply change all the Form1s in it to whatever you've renamed Form1 to?

Comment: Thanks Guys, Its now working, "I unloaded the project, and when i re-loaded it, it generated the the Tab! Thank you so much for your help on this, panic stricken!!!